# How to get parent node with ancestors xpath in html agility pack

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

How to get parent node with ancestors XPath in HTML document in HTML Agility Pack (HAP)? For example, I have one HTML document please check below:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <a>
                                        <h3>
                                        </h3>
                                    </a>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to get the parent node and their ancestors path in HAP. For example, the XPath of the above HTML document is

```
/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/a/h3
```

Expect xpath will be

```
/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]
```

Note that I need to get the expected Xpath dynamically - not as a manually hardcode value. For example, based on the last element I need to get the parent with ancestors path.

Comment: `<div1>` is not valid HTML tag (as well as `<div2>`). Update your question properly and add your current code, current output

Comment: @Andersson,Thanks for your information...